# Does retrieving a database backup restore user password in OVH?

Tags: database, ovh

I have a couple of databases that it's user's passwords have been changed and i plan on changing them back to their old passwords so im wondering, if i retrieve a database a backup from ovh does that affect the user credentials or just the tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you restore your backup (the ones automatically made each day by OVH), it will only restore your tables and relations, **not** the users.

If you want to double check this, you can download your backup files and check its content. You should not see any `CREATE USER` instruction inside this backup file.